# When should we use jaccard score?

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, pandas, logistic-regression, numpy

I am a newbie in Machine Learning, I trained a binary classifier for bank loan prediction through Logistic Regression.
I measured the accuracy of it with two methods: accuracy score and jaccard index.
Accuracy score returns a value of 0.91 whereas jaccard score returns a value of 33.
Why is jaccard sore showing such a low value.(Ik it is a really stupid question, but it would be really good if you could help me out)

Answer (score 1):

The Jaccard index or score is often used for bounding boxes or semantic segmentation in machine learning, i.e. in computer vision problems. Your problem is a classification problem using tabular data, and therefore this metric is not really applicable for this type of problem. Accuracy (and maybe even more so precision and recall) are more valuable metrics to assess your model's accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Jaccard score is a similarity coefficient (i.e., how similar are two sets).

Mathematical formula is:

J(A, B) = |A∩B| / |A∪B|

In your case of binary classification, F-1, Precision, Recall are all better metrics for evaluating model performance (as @Oxbowerce mentioned). An important thing to keep in mind when evaluating model performance for classification problems is the distribution of your data (balanced vs imbalanced). For highly imbalanced datasets, F-1/Precision/Recall scores would most accurately describe how your model is predicting positive classes, as compared to Accuracy Score (read: [Accuracy Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_paradox))